# get all hashes from array from hashes where values are true in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of hashes as below. I want to get only those hashes where values are true

```
array = [{id:1, name: 'A'},{id: 2, name: 'B'},{id: 3, name: 'C'},{id:4, name: 'D'}]

values = [2, 4]
```

I only want those hashes where id is 2, 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `filter` method, which returns a new array only with the elements that return True.
In this case the condition to return True is that `values` includes the element id.

```
let filteredArray = array.filter(element => {
  return values.includes(element.id);
});
```